# How do digital newspaper libraries' search engines work?

Tags: search, full-text-search

For example, if I search the word "mexico" in the National Newspaper Library, one of the results looks like this:

http://www.hndm.unam.mx/consulta/resultados/visualizar/558a36117d1ed64f16c21cdc?resultado=2&tipo=pagina&intPagina=1&palabras=mexico

The site is able to highlight my search term. Nonetheless, the exportable PDF doesn't contain (apparently) any of the data that the search engine uses to match my query. In fact it is a /Subtype/Image PDF file.

Where is the text information and how is the engine able to highlight the result on the PDF doc?